# Computing the parametric equation of the line of intersection of two planes

Tags: calculus, geometry, parametric

I'm given the following problem:

> Find the parametric equation of the line of intersection of the two given planes: $y-6z = 7$ and $9x - 8y = 5$

My attempted solution follows:

I take the cross product of two vectors normal to the given planes, $<0,1,-6> \times <9,-8,0>$, and obtain the vector $<-48,-54,-9>$. I then set $z=0$, and solve the given simultaneous equations to determine a point along the line of intersection, $(\frac{61}{9}, {7}, 0)$. I can then write the parametric equation of intersection as:

$x = \frac{61}{9} - 48t$, $y = 7 - 54t$, $z = -9t$, using parameter $t$

Unfortunately, however, it seems I've erred in my solution. Is this the proper technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cross product will give you the direction of the line of intersection, yes!

However the line may or may not pass through $z=0$ (e.g. it could be parallel to the XY plane) so this method doesn't guarantee a solution.

The simplest way to get a solution would just be to solve the system of equations, by substitution:

$y-6z = 7$ implies $y = 6z + 7$.

Plugging this into the $9x -8y=5$, you get $9x-42z-56 = 5$ which is the line you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Shouldn't the "...however the line may or may not pass through $z=0$" be taken care of by finding the point of intersection where $z=0$, though?

Comment: That's what I mean! You cannot, since the line of intersection may not pass through $z=0$ (for two arbitrary planes).